# Moose basics: open file and parse

Tags: perl, oop, moose

I am new to [`Moose`](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose) and OOP and would like some guidance on solving a very basic file handling and parsing requirement using `Moose`. I am familiar with Perl, and would like to start using OOP.

Essentially, all that I want to do is open a text file, parse it, and print to `stdout`.

For instance using standard Perl

```
open (FILE , input.txt);
while (FILE)
{
  if (/(\S+)\s+(\d+)/)
  {
    print "$1-$2";
  }
}
```

where input.txt is

```
ABC 20
DEF 10
GHI 50
```

Comment: @user621092 use 3 argument open as seen in the [first example in the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) also what's this got to do with Moose? I'm confused on what you mean by parsing requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Opening files doesn't really relate to Moose in any way. However, if you are looking for existing interfaces to deal with files, you should take a look at [Path::Class::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Path%3a%3aClass%3a%3aFile), which is an object that will contain a filename and provide you many methods for dealing with the file it represents. It is quite common to use this class as a Moose type constraint in an attribute:

```
package MyApp::Foo;

use Moose;

has filename => (
    is => 'ro', isa => 'Path::Class::File',
);

sub process_file
{
    my $this = shift;

    if (-e $this->filename)
    {
        my $fh = $this->filename->openr;
        while (my $line = <$fh>)
        {
             # process file, line by line...
        }
    }
}

package main;

my $obj = MyApp::Foo->new(filename => '/home/me/foo.txt');
$obj->process_file;
```

You could also modify the `process_file` method so it takes a coderef which receives one line from the file as an argument, to process the file contents in a more modular way.  It all depends on what you need your program to do, of course.

Alternatively, if you like [MooseX::Types](http://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aTypes), you can do:

```
use MooseX::Types::Path::Class qw(Dir File);
has file => ( ..., isa => File, coerce => 1, ... );
```

This will let you pass a filename to the attribute and it will automatically inflate into a `Path::Class::File` object internally.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try emulating examples in [Moose::Cookbook](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aCookbook).

To be honest, your own example is not really OOP related.

If you mean using OOP version of IO, you can easily do that (use `IO::Handle`) module, but that module is not Moose based.

If you mean you want to wrap the file code above into a Moose-based module, you certainly can but you need to clarify the (Moose-independent) OOP design you want. E.g. what are the instance variables you seek? methods?

Comment: What I am looking for is a function I can call that will parse a file based on input parameters eg. my $v=CLASS->new(); $v->parseLog($logfile,'MOC','2011-02-15','ABC'); and return data from $logfile for 'MOC','2011-02-15','ABC'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment under DVK's answer, you might be asking for something like this?

```
package CORDx;
use Moose;
use Carp;

sub parse_log {
    my ($self,$input_name, $whatever) = @_;
    open my $fh, "<", $input_name
        or croak "\"$input_name\" not found";

    while(<$fh>) {
        if(/(\S+)\s+(\d+)/) {
            print "$1-$2";
        }
    }
}


package main;
use CORDx;

my $cordr = CORDx->new();
$cordr->parse_log('input.txt');
```

Comment: Thank you and much appreciated... is it this simple? for someone new to Moose the above makes sense and going to same me a lot of time.

Comment: @bvr - where's the Moose-specific part? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DVK: `use Moose;` Therefore, it uses Moose!

Comment: @CanSpice - Ah! I am enlightened! :)

Comment: @DVK - from question and comments it looks that OP considers OOP and Moose being deep complex magic. This only shows how to build trivial class with Moose. I realize that only thing you get is (simple) constructor, but from this you can continue easier than building the class for yourself.

Comment: As mentioned I am new to OOP. My objective is to start using Moose as it simplifies OOP in perl. OOP will allow me to write code once only. The example which I gave (file parsing) is simplistic, however I am more interested in concepts. I hope this clarifies all issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple Perl program and using `Moose` would only complicate it.

Before you progress to writing object-oriented Perl

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program
- Use lexical filehandles, the three-argument form of `open` and *always* check the success of every `open` call

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;

/(\S+)\s+(\d+)/ and print "$1-$2\n" while <$fh>;
```